# Differentiating feature of Jbehave

Tags: bdd

I just came to know about jbehave. Can anyone tell me what is the differentiating feature of jbehave with regard to the other BDD tools like Cucumber, FiTNesse, Concordion?

Answer (score 3):

[JBehave](http://www.jbehave.org) is most similar to Cucumber in its operation and syntax. JBehave was the original BDD tool and written in native Java. Cucumber was inspired by JBehave and written in Ruby.

[Cucumber-JVM](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) is a native Java implementation of Cucumber that implements "step definitions" using annotations (like JBehave) and regular expressions to identify parameters (like Ruby Cucumber). Both JBehave and Cucumber use text-based feature files. There really isn't a significant difference between JBehave and Cucumber, except that Cucumber is far more widely adopted than JBehave (thanks to its cross-platform nature and its developers efforts).

[FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) uses a Wiki with special syntax to define the test specs and Java "fixtures" to interpret them. It's clumsy and ugly, but has been around a while so still has some users.

[Concordion](http://www.concordion.org) uses HTML to define the test specs, and uses a Java (JUnit) fixture to run them. The main difference between FitNesse and Concordion (apart from FitNesse using a Wiki) is that FitNesse fixtures are reusable, whereas Concordion's are customized to the specific scenario. This tends to make Concordion fixtures simpler and reduces duplication and irrelevant values in test specs.

Assuming you are working in Java, I would recommend Cucumber (if the audience is only developers) or Concordion (if the audience for the specs may also include non-developers). Concordion specs are in HTML which means they can be hyperlinked together and double-up as nicely formatted documentation.